# How to specify excel rows quantity for import

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using maatwebsite/excel 3.1,when importing excel file with 5 rows and 34 columns of data, it takes 500 rows and each row contains 703 columns and I need to decrease memory usage.

How to specify rows quantity and columns too?

```
...
 public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
      ...
      foreach($rows as $row){
        if (!$row[0]) {
            return;
        }
        ...
        $productArray = [...]
        $this->product = $this->importProduct($row, $productArray);
       }
    }
    ...
   
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 350;
    }
```

Comment: if you want to decrease memory usage read it by chunk https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html

Comment: Yes I used read by chunk, but no differences.

Comment: have you tried to decrease the chunk size to 20 / 30 to check if there is a difference at least? with 703 columns, 350 seems a lot.

Comment: also no differences.

Comment: I solved this by replacing import with rap2hpoutre/fast-excel.